# pass two jsp pages to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

hello everyone I am new to web. Here is the problem.
I have two JSP pages, I want get data form both all them using one servlet.

```
1.jsp
<form action="2.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="jsp1">
</form>


2.jsp
<form action="servlet">
    <input type="text" name="jsp2">
</form>

servlet.java
request.getParameter("jsp1");
request.getParameter("jsp2");
```

Comment: That's impossible. The user can't submit two forms at the same time (if that's what you want to do, but it's not very clear). Each form submission sends one request.

Comment: 1.jsp jump to 2.jsp, then 2.jsp pass all the data to servlet, is that achieveable?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send 2 requests at same time 
but as described you need to send params from first page to second page and then you need to send params from second page(included params from first page) to servlet (the following example is not a perfect solution but it is as described)
Here an Example :

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="index2.jsp">
  <input type="text" name="text1" />
  <input type="text" name="text2" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

index2.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Enumeration" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="servlet">
    <%

        String page1="";

        Enumeration<String>names=request.getParameterNames();

        while (names.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String name=names.nextElement();
            String value=request.getParameter(name);


            page1+=name+"="+value+"&";


        }

        if(page1.length()>0)
            page1=page1.substring(0,page1.length()-1);


    %>


    <input type="hidden" name="page1" value="<%=page1%>" />
    <input type="text" name="text3" />
    <input type="text" name="text4" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />


</form>

</body>
```

Servlet :

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class TestServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

        String page1=request.getParameter("page1");
        String text3=request.getParameter("text3");
        String text4=request.getParameter("text4");

        System.out.println(" page1 "+page1);
        System.out.println(" text3 "+text3);
        System.out.println(" text4 "+text4);

    }

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

        doPost(request,response);
    }
}
```

web.xml :

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>mypackage.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```